# Fastjson ToObject transform null to empty string

Tags: json, fastjson

I use FastJSON to deserialize a json into an object. During the deserialization I would like to automatically replace all the null values in the json by an empty string. Is there a JSON parameter to do that? Otherwise, what would you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JSON.parseObject(String json, Class<T> clazz, Feature... features)` method and pass through `Feature.InitStringFieldAsEmpty` as last argument.